# What is the difference between BeautifulSoup's site.content and site.read()?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

When I use a local html file stored on my laptop,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
site = open('smpl.htm', 'r')
page = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'html.parser')
print(page)
```

returns (in the cmd):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/~~~~~~/python/h.py", line 3, in <module>
page = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'html.parser')
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'content'
```

but by replacing `site.content` with `site.read()`, the code shows the correct HTML and performs operations on it without any problems.

However, if I get my HTML file from the web through `requests`, then I'll have to write `site.content` and not `site.read()` to parse it.

What is the difference between content and read() and which is appropriate for what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a html file on your laptop returns a TextIOWrapper which has a read() method to get the contents of the file.

Opening a web page uses a different class with different methods - the one you reference looks to return some form of HttpResponse object with a contents string parameter.